# Slim 3 get from API?

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

Is there a way using Slim 3 to get data from an api endpoint? I've searched on google and there doesn't seem to be any way to do this from my research.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make HTTP calls to external API using any HTTP client. For example, [guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle). For more info, go to [this link](http://discourse.slimframework.com/t/best-way-to-call-external-api-in-slim/860). Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin PHP function `file_get_contents`.

$json = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/api');